# xgboost in R and cross validation

Tags: r, prediction, xgboost

I use xgboost package in R.

First, I want to tune the parameters with the validation set(20% of the data set).
Second, I want to get model and predict to binary classification task with 5-fold cross validation. I use 64%(80%*80%) for the train set and 16%(80%*20%) for test set and iterate this five times.

First, I use xgb.cv for tuning parameters.
Related questions are [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/otto-group-product-classification-challenge/forums/t/13053/xgboost-and-cross-validation) and  [xgboost in R: how does xgb.cv pass the optimal parameters into xgb.train](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35050846/xgboost-in-r-how-does-xgb-cv-pass-the-optimal-parameters-into-xgb-train) .

```
set.seed(650)
tr.num<-sample(650,130)###I have 650 samples.
data.tuning<-data[tr.num,]
data.traintest<-data[-tr.num,]

x.tune <- data.tuning[,2:9]
x.tune <- as.matrix(x.tune)
k<-round(1+log2(130))
cv.nround <- 200 #search
bst.cv <- xgb.cv(param=param, data = x.tune, label = data.tuning[,10],nfold = k, nrounds=cv.nround, metrics=list("error"), prediction = TRUE)
```

> ......
>
> [2] train-error:0.017573+0.008109  test-error:0.108456+0.104800
>
> [3]    train-error:0.013177+0.006646   test-error:0.100643+0.100299
>
> [4]    train-error:0.008782+0.004689   test-error:0.100643+0.100299
>
> [5]    train-error:0.003299+0.004553   test-error:0.100643+0.100299
>
> [6]    train-error:0.000000+0.000000   test-error:0.100643+0.100299
>
> [7]    train-error:0.000000+0.000000   test-error:0.108456+0.104800
>
> [8]    train-error:0.000000+0.000000   test-error:0.107996+0.086933
>
> ......

I selected nround = 7 becase of the minimun test-error.

Second, I use xgb.cv again for 5-fold cross validation in order to get the model and to know the precision and recall.
But how should I do?

```
x.traintest <- data.traintest[,2:9]
x.traintest <- as.matrix(x.traintest)
bst.cv <- xgb.cv(param=param, data = x.traintest, label = data.traintest[,10], nrounds=7, nfold = 5)

test <- 1:104 ###650*0.16 = 104
train <- 105:520

y.traintest <- data.traintest[,10]
y.traintest <- as.matrix(y.traintest)

bst <- xgboost(param=param, data = x.traintest[train,], label=y.traintest[train,], nrounds=7, nfold = 5)
pred <- predict(bst,x.traintest[test,])
for(i in 1:length(pred)){
  if(pred[i] > 0.5) {pred[i]="case"}
  else {pred[i]="no"}
}
table(y.traintest[test,],pred)
```

Is this 5-fold cross validation and prediction?
I want to get the average recall and precision of 5-fold cross validation. How should I do?
I don't understand how to use PREDICTION = TRUE also.

Related questions is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38815666/tuning-xgboost-with-xgb-train-providing-a-validation-set-in-r), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36523319/is-it-possible-to-cross-validate-and-save-the-cross-validated-model-with-xgboost), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32433458/how-to-specify-train-and-test-indices-for-xgb-cv-in-r-package-xgboost?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Do I misunderstand about cross validation or gradient boosting?